# GirdView / ScrollViewer without zoom in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm using in my C# app a ScrollViewer and in this a GridView. Not it is possible to zoom in and out, but in my case I don't need this functionaliy. How can I disable zoom in and out?

Here is little examle:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1">
    <GridView x:Name="Cards" Margin="4,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding EmergencyCards}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmergencyCardTemplate}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `ZoomMode="Disabled"` in the `ScrollViewer` tag. -

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
```